# What is the relationship between cancer and sugar?

Tags: nutrition, diet, cancer, sugar, fad-diet

I was watching "The Magic Pill" documentary series on Netflix.  And, a woman indicated that she completely cured a fairly aggressive breast cancer by eliminating just about all sugars and most carbohydrates.  She followed a very strict keto diet.  Having done a bit of research on the issue, I could not find any solid scientific evidence and/or replication of her experience.

I don't doubt this woman did cure herself in the fashion she did.  I just suspect there may have been a ton of confounding factors that she did not take into account.  And, instead attributed 100% of her cure to her diet alteration only.

Comment: I would go with your instincts on confounding factors. The question in your title is extremely broad, and we have to watch a Netflix documentary to know the specifics of what you're asking? Your question is entirely too broad and lacks prior research. It would be a fit on Skeptics.SE but I think they'll also require more prior research so I can't migrate it.

Comment: I believe the question is narrow enough, because in studies they often take "sugar" as one category and "cancer" as one category as well. So, this type of research is initially very easy. A suggestion: [site:gov sugar cancer "systematic review"](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=5NI7Xp-uI9LhgwfC2qKQAg&q=site%3Agov+sugar+cancer+%22systematic+review%22&oq=site%3Agov+sugar+cancer+%22systematic+review%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1520.12614..14323...0.0..0.59.1968.41......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0.AwriWBzZUiE&ved=0ahUKEwifsOG1xbznAhXS8OAKHUKtCCIQ4dUDCAY&uact=5)...(use quotes as shown)

Comment: With this search, you pretty much narrow down the results to [PubMed (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/), which is a big collection of articles from various medical journals. "Systematic review" narrows down the results to systematic reviews of studies, so you don't need to check dozens of individual studies. Articles have clearly organized abstracts with 1-2 sentence long "conclusions." So, when you get familiar with this, you can get some initial insight literally within a minute.

Comment: Yes, I did go to PubMed and the related PMC websites.  At PMC, I found an excellent study with very large samples testing mortality rates for cancer, CVD, and others by gender in association with different levels of sugar intakes grouped in quintiles.  They also tested for numerous different types of sugar.  And, the results were not conclusive.  In most cases, the mortality risk for high consumer of sugars (top quintile) vs low consumer of sugars (bottom quintile) was not that different (ratio close to 1.0).

Comment: When results are not conclusive and when the risk is ~1.0, you can assume there is no significant relationship (at least not in this study). I personally doubt that a measure simple like removing sugar from diet would treat cancer, because this would be widely known by now. In short (and in general), foods, diets and herbs do not likely cure cancers.